# Barplots using centroids in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, polygon, errorbar

I'll like to create several barplots using centroid locations to position them. I already have a plot code for the polygons I want to combine them with. These are from a floor plan and not a geographical area around the world. Unfortunately, I have several points unlike the example in the link below which has just three points. How do I plot this using ggplot2 to cover all my points? Here is the sample ggplot code I want to add the barplot to:

```
ggplot() + theme_minimal()+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,face="bold",size=14),line=element_line(size=0.2),
                              panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                              axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),strip.text = element_text(size=11, face = "bold"),axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                              axis.title.y = element_blank(),legend.title=element_text(size=9, face = "bold"))+
  geom_polygon(aes(x =long, y = lat, group = group), size=0.5,color="black",fill="black",alpha=0.2, data =shp1_data.frame)+
  geom_polygon(aes(x =long, y = lat, group = group), size=0.5,color="white",fill="black",alpha=0.2, data =shp4_data.frame)
```

[image: Example of barplots of geographical locations]

[Codes for the image attached](http://papacochon.com/2015/10/18/Codage-12-r-visualization-3-bubble-bar-on-map/)

```
head(read.table("Sampledata.txt",header=T),15)
   Location_i variable      value        x         y
1        A005     Head  0.0000000 1238.509 -970.4791
2        A005     Hair  0.0000000 1238.509 -970.4791
3        A005    Knees  0.1666667 1238.509 -970.4791
4        A005     Ears  0.0000000 1238.509 -970.4791
5        A005    Heart  0.0000000 1238.509 -970.4791
6        A005    Mouth -0.1666667 1238.509 -970.4791
7        A005     Toes  0.0000000 1238.509 -970.4791
8        A028     Head  0.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
9        A028     Hair  0.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
10       A028    Knees  0.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
11       A028     Ears  0.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
12       A028    Heart  1.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
13       A028    Mouth -1.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
14       A028     Toes  0.0000000 1538.509 -870.4791
15       A030     Toes  0.0000000 1738.509 -870.6731
```

I have put a sample of the data [Here in my drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l5bfEv08-5Y2cwNH-SUCbGT6Y8YNBROG) with the x and y location fields, value, variable ad location ID. the plot is grouped around each centroid (location_i) using the variable field.

```
##To read in the text file after downloading
  A1<-read.table("Sampledata.txt",header=T)
```

Comment: Please post a sample of just the data you intend to plot, directly in the question, so people don't have to download it or filter for the data you're trying to display

Comment: Ok. I have just added the first 14 lines of the data.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? What trouble are you having with adapting the code from the tutorial to your project?

Comment: The example in the tutorial is good when there are few barplots to be plotted. When it increases to 20, it becomes cumbersome. I'm looking for a code to automatically plot the barplots and position them for each row in the dataframe. Something along the lines of "for i in length(A1)" is what I am desperate fore.

Comment: That makes sense, although I believe in the tutorial they had a geom_col for each color of bar, but not for each location. Do you mean that you'll need many bars at each location? If not, the number of locations shouldn't matter

Comment: About 7 bars for each location and there are about 50 locations. The colour coding won't be a problem as there are just 7 of them.